# The use of "to" in some titles

Tags: titles

While I'm browsing Reddit, I sometimes find a title which contains "to" in the sentence even though it might be totally unnecessary.

What is the difference between :

> Yahoo stops all new development on ...

and

> Yahoo to stop all new development on ...

?

The two sentences mean the same, but which one should I use, and which one is grammatically correct ?

Comment: Without a finite verb, you don’t have much of a sentence — more like a headline, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are different.

> Yahoo stops all new development on X.

Means that Yahoo! have stopped developing product X, there will be no more improvements.

> Yahoo to stop all new development on ...

Means that Yahoo! will stop developing product X, there will be no more improvements, after a set date. They are *going* to stop it, and have planned to, but they haven't yet.

For example:

> Canonical to stop supporting Ubuntu 13.04
> -- posted before July 17, 2014
>
> Canonical stop supporting Ubuntu 13.04
> -- posted on or after July 17, 2014

Comment: Or they *plan* to stop it. (Which leads to the same ultimate result, of course.) This seems to be one of those constructions where it is left to the reader to decide what missing verb best fits the situation.

Comment: This construction could also be used if, for example, you were allotting roles to people, ie giving them instructions. eg Zaidar to greet people at the door, Tim to show them to their seats, Mynamite to serve the drinks.